# filtering Future API

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Can i filter Asynchronous call. Does future provide some filter where i can add condition to wait until first call is complete not put time.

```
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   public class FactorialCalculator implements Callable<BigInteger> {

    private int value;

    public FactorialCalculator(int value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger call() throws Exception {

        var result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

        if (value == 0 || value == 1) {

            result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        } else {

            for (int i = 2; i <= value; i++) {

                result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `CompletableFuture` class and especially the `CompletionStage` interface it implements. This allows you to chain asynchronous actions together as you imply you want to do.

Something like this perhaps:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> getBoth = CompletableFuture
    .completeAsync(getBase,executor)
    .thenApplyAsync(getTar,executor);
```

This will run the `getBase` Supplier to get the base WSDL, and then if it completes normally run a Function<WSDL,Result> to get the second datum and combine it with the first to create the Result.

Comment: i like this. currently i using ExecutorService in Future. for  CompletableFuture what method can i use. or can i use the same ExecutorService?

Comment: @Ameri just pass in your `ExecutorService` instance as the executor parameter to one of the *Async methods. It will then use the executor service to run the provided tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The get() method of future waits for result to complete, and then retrieves its result.

```
 ExecResult execResult = getingWsdl.get();
```

Or you can use a overload method get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) that wait for at most the given time for the execution to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available

```
ExecResult execResult = getingWsdl.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or you can also put execResult into a Thread and wait for a condition in run() method to evaluate execResult. Observe that if you want a return from Thread you can use Callable interface and ExecutorService instead Runnable and Thread.